# bitbucket .gitignore .DS_Store ignores enclosing directories as well

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore

Bitbucket .gitignore with DS_Store ignores enclosing directories as well, and all the other files in that directory. 
Let's say I have .DS_Store in my .gitignore. 
I change  and add file to a directory. 
Since .DS_Store file was created, the entire dir and other files are ignored.
I want to commit my other changes, but bitbucket is ignoring them!

How to configure this so .DS_Store files stay out of my bitbucket?

Comment: The wording of your question makes it sound like git is ignoring all of the contents of any directory that contains a .DS_Store, which would be untrue unless that directory was a child of a directory named .DS_Store. Maybe you can share your .gitignore contents, and directory structure?

Comment: "The wording of your question makes it sound like git is ignoring all of the contents of any directory that contains a .DS_Store" . that is EXACTLY what is happening. the only entry in the .gitignore is .DS_Store

Comment: Can you post your .gitignore file, and maybe explain your directory and file layout? That is not how Git is supposed to work, so I suspect you have something odd in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you included your .gitignore file as well as the files you are trying to add.

Depending on what you want to accomplish one of the following should work.

If you want the files to remain ignored but add them any way then use the -f option (-f/--force
Allow adding otherwise ignored files.) to `git add`

```
git add -f <some_file>
```

If you want to unignore them then you need to reconfigure your .gitignore.  One way might look like

```
.gitignore 
.DS_Store
!.DS_Store/file_to_be_added
```

You can find all kinds of examples of specific .gitignores and howtos by searching SO.

Answer (score 0):

*(This isn't really an answer, but wanted space to put code)*

For sanity sake, try doing this in a new/empty directory on the console/shell:

```
git init
touch .DS_Store
touch otherFile.txt
echo .DS_Store> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git status
```

The result *should* be:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .gitignore

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        otherFile.txt
```